# Disable automatic rearrange ios

Tags: ipad, ios

Is it possible to disable automatic rearrange of background apps in iOS 8?

For example if I open ibooks notepad and skype, when i answer to skype message app stands in first place, after switching to ibooks skype will be on second place, but it's not comfortable because I want go with swype to notepad and write note. it is become more complicated if open more apps.

So is it possible to lock background app positions (or pin like in browsers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible** on an un-jailbroken iOS device.

The apps in the app-switcher are sorted by how recently they were last open (most recent on the left). You can not modify this behaviour.

The app-switcher is designed to let the user open apps that they used recently. It isn't designed to open a user's favourite apps - that's the home screen's job.

Try to organise your most-used/favourite apps together on one page on the home screen for quick access.